# Orbeon Forms Liferay plugin

Tags: liferay, orbeon

I'm new to Orbeon Forms, I would like to use the Liferay portlet plugin but I cannot find the download file: there is only in the nightly build. Is it possible to have a more stable version to try it?

Answer (score 0):

The most stable version of the Orbeon Forms portlet support is the one in the nightly builds, as there has just been a series of bug-fixes for the upcoming Orbeon Forms 3.9 release.

It's technically not a plugin: you just deploy a [nightly build of the Orbeon Forms PE orbeon.war](http://forge.ow2.org/nightlybuilds/ops/ops/orbeon-PE.war) into Liferay and the Orbeon Forms portlet will be available.